# Access state values from parent using react native navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I'm using createStackNavigator like this:

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        title: 'Account Details',
        headerLeft : <Back nav={ navigation } goto={'Profile'}/>,
        headerRight: <Icon
            name='check'
            color='#fff'
            onPress={() => **SOME FUNCTION** }
        />
    }
}
```

This header loads in the 'Account Details' form, where they can edit their username etc. I want to use the 'check' Icon in the header to save the information entered.

Is there a way I can tell it to use a function that exists inside my 'Account Details' component, so I can access the state values from in there? Or somehow pass them back to the parent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass that function to `state` of `navigation` and use it normally

```js
class YourComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      yourFuntion: this._yourfunction,
    })
  }
  
  yourfunction = () => {
    // handle thing with state here
  }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
    const yourFuntion = navigation.getParam("yourFuntion", ()=>{});
    return {
        ...
        headerRight: <Icon
            name='check'
            color='#fff'
            onPress={() => yourFuntion() }
        />
        ...
    }
}
```