# How to access parent state values from a custom react navigation header component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This question is similar to this one
[Access state values from parent using react native navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923530/access-state-values-from-parent-using-react-native-navigation)

except in the linked question it is using the default react navigation header config, I am using a custom one.

```
//code in the parent
static navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle: <MyCustomHeader/>, //my custom header component
        headerStyle: { //applies to the View
            backgroundColor: colors.darkThemeBackground,
        },
        headerTintColor: colors.whiteText,
    };
```

The parent contains a flatlist and there is a button in my custom header component that when I press it, I want it to be able to update data in the flatlist. That would mean that my custom header component needs access to the parents state values.

Im not sure how to do this with my custom component header.

Comment: You can do this using params, set the params in consructor and use the callback version of the `navigationOptions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same as [the answer from the question you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51923664/9119186) but just pass the props you want

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      yourFuntion: this._yourfunction,
    })
  }

  yourfunction = () => {
    // handle thing with state here
  }
}

navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        const yourFuntion = navigation.getParam("yourFuntion", ()=>{});
        headerTitle: <MyCustomHeader yourFuntion={yourFuntion}/>, //pass what you want in prop
        headerStyle: { //applies to the View
            backgroundColor: colors.darkThemeBackground,
        },
        headerTintColor: colors.whiteText,
    };
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but what I understood from your question is that you want to get a prop in the component and passe it to your custom header, so do like the other question, but just pass it in props